# Javascript: Is there a way to FindControl like in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#

Please no jQuery solutions! I am still learning JavaScript.

I have a function that breaks down some of the DOM elements based on a given `checkbox` control.

```
            function highlightRow(chk) {
                var cell = chk.parentNode;
                var row = cell.parentNode;
                var tbody = row.parentNode;
                var rows = tbody.children;
                var hrow = rows[0];                         //get header row
-->             var hCbox = hrow.getElementsByID("cbHDR");  //get 'cbHDR' checkbox that's in the header

                if (chk.checked) {
                    addClass(row, 'selected-row');
                }
                else {
                    removeClass(row, 'selected-row');
                }
    ..etc
    }
```

The problem I am having is the line shown ...

> var hCbox = hrow.getElementsByID("cbHDR");

How do I find elements based on a given element, such as in this case the HeaderRow of a Gridview?

The above returns null. In fact I don't even know if it even runs, as I am not sure if `getElementsByID()` is purely a method for the `document` object.

I am trying to avoid using document.get... as it retrieves ALL header checkboxes across 4 GridViews in my case. I am trying to find the Header checkbox based on the HeaderRow **only.**

Thanks

Comment: The correct one is `document.getElementById("cbHDR")`. Additionally, if you using ASPX page make sure you have static client-side id, otherwise you need to use `document.getElementById("<%= cbHDR.ClientID %>")`.

Comment: “In fact I don't even know if it even runs, as I am not sure if `getElementsByID()` is purely a method for the document object.” You’re right; it’s only on `document`. It’s also capitalized differently. You would know this by looking at your browser’s console.

Comment: Updated question @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Can you provide `GridView` markup details? I see that you need something like this: `var grid = document.getElementById('<%= GridView.ClientID %>');` then get header checkbox value using `var headerCheckBox = tbl.rows[n].cells[n].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id` (n = row/column index).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto That's precisely what I am trying to avoid - hardcoded pathways. Answered below anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in pure javascript, finding an element by tag name can be done with querySelector on the containing element. So if you've already obtained a reference to the dom element for the gridview (say, using getElementById), captured in a variable called `gridView`, then:

```
let headerRow = gridView.querySelector('HeaderRow');
```

BTW `let` is es6 syntax. So if you're worried about old browser compatibility, use `var` instead.

Comment: Yes. I just found that sneaky function just then too. querySelector(). Thanks!